# How to initialize extern variables in a namespace

Tags: c++, initialization, extern

I have a global.h that looks like:

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>

namespace qe
{

    class SubSystemA;
    class SubSystemB;
    class SubSystemC;

    namespace Systems
    {

        extern std::unique_ptr<SubSystemA> gSubSystemA;
        extern std::unique_ptr<SubSystemB> gSubSystemB;
        extern std::unique_ptr<SubSystemC> gSubSystemC;

    }

}
```

Now I'm not sure if I can initialize it in my main.cpp but w/e I'm doing, it's not working ... please advice. Here's what main looks like:

```
#include "SubSystemA.h"
#include "SubSystemB.h"
#include "SubSystemC.h"
#include "global.h"

int main()
{

    extern std::unique_ptr<qe::SubSystemA> qe::Systems::gSubSystemA;
    extern std::unique_ptr<qe::SubSystemB> qe::Systems::gSubSystemB;
    extern std::unique_ptr<qe::SubSystemC> qe::Systems::gSubSystemC;

    qe::Systems::gSubSystemA = std::make_unique<qe::SubSystemA>();
    qe::Systems::gSubSystemB = std::make_unique<qe::SubSystemB>();
    qe::Systems::gSubSystemC = std::make_unique<qe::SubSystemC>();

    return 0;
}
```

Basically I get "unresolved external symbol" error and I'm not sure how I can fix it. Any help is appreciated thanks!

Edit: while solving this is nice to know, alternative suggestions on doing this are welcome. I just want to have easy (doesn't means global but I don't mind it) access to sub system like objects.

Comment: In cpp file remove the `extern` declarations; you did `#include "global.h" `already. Add definitions for those items to one of your .cpp files. You could either have initializers on the definitions, or use assignment statements as you currently are.

Comment: Removing makes it a compile error saying re-definition. Removing the entire line (the 3 unique_ptr<>) still gives me the linker error while compiles fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define(initialize) them out of `main()` (i.e. in namespace scope), and don't use `extern` specifier, which indicates a declaration. e.g.

```
std::unique_ptr<qe::SubSystemA> qe::Systems::gSubSystemA = std::make_unique<qe::SubSystemA>();
std::unique_ptr<qe::SubSystemB> qe::Systems::gSubSystemB = std::make_unique<qe::SubSystemB>();
std::unique_ptr<qe::SubSystemC> qe::Systems::gSubSystemC = std::make_unique<qe::SubSystemC>();

int main()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: What if they are order dependent? Say I want B, A, then C in that order. I think C++11 and onwards should initialize them in the order that you type them ... but I want to confirm that.

Comment: @ChaoSXDemon Within a single translation unit, initialization of these variables is always sequenced in exact order their definitions appear in the source code. Initialization order of variables across different translation units is indeterminate.

Answer (score 3):

The lines

```
qe::Systems::gSubSystemA = std::make_unique<qe::SubSystemA>();
qe::Systems::gSubSystemB = std::make_unique<qe::SubSystemB>();
qe::Systems::gSubSystemC = std::make_unique<qe::SubSystemC>();
```

in `main` don't define the variables. They assign values to the variables. They need to be defined outside all functions. It's best to define them in the .cpp file corresponding to the .h file in which they are declared. In your case, that file should be global.cpp. Add the following lines outside all namespace.

```
qe::Systems::gSubSystemA = std::make_unique<qe::SubSystemA>();
qe::Systems::gSubSystemB = std::make_unique<qe::SubSystemB>();
qe::Systems::gSubSystemC = std::make_unique<qe::SubSystemC>();
```

You can also use:

```
namespace qe
{
   namespace Systems
   {
      gSubSystemA = std::make_unique<SubSystemA>();
      gSubSystemB = std::make_unique<SubSystemB>();
      gSubSystemC = std::make_unique<SubSystemC>();
   }
}
```

or in C++17:

```
namespace qe::Systems
{
  gSubSystemA = std::make_unique<SubSystemA>();
  gSubSystemB = std::make_unique<SubSystemB>();
  gSubSystemC = std::make_unique<SubSystemC>();
}
```

Comment: If I initialize them inside the global.h file, I would need to include all those headers, I wanted to avoid that but thanks for that suggestion.

Comment: @ChaoSXDemon, perhaps you misunderstood. You define and initialize the variables in a .cpp file, not in a .h file. You need to `#include` only one .h file wherever you need to use the variables.